Question about pressure maximization in accelerating fluid systems
I'm working on a problem from our physics class related to pressure in a fluid system, and I could use some clarification. Here’s the scenario:

We define the origin at the bottom left, with +x to the right and +z upwards. Using the first equation, I separated the components:
-∂P/∂x + 0 = ρ ax

-∂P/∂x + ρgk = ρ az
We express the acceleration vector as:
a = ax + az

a = (-4)i + 0k
This allows us to simplify the equations to:
-∂ P/ ∂ x = ρ (-4) i

-∂ P/ ∂ z + ρ g k = 0
After integrating both equations and combining them, we arrive at:
P = 4 ρ x - ρ g z
At this point, we concluded that pressure P is maximized at x=L and z=0, yielding the result 4ρL.
My Questions:

Are we correctly defining ( g = -9.8 k)? Wouldn't this imply that the maximum pressure occurs at the top right corner instead of the bottom right?

If that’s the case, it seems contradictory because we know that in a stationary fluid, pressure increases with depth. Intuitively, this suggests that the maximum pressure should indeed be at the bottom right.

Lastly, how does accelerating the fluid to the left affect the pressure at the bottom of the container in a way that makes it independent of height? Am I misunderstanding something here?


I appreciate any insights or clarifications you can provide!

If you put dollar signs $ around your equations, it looks better. Try this MathJax tutorial

It is easiest to work this problem using a non-inertial coordinate system in which the observer is accelerating to the left along with the container.  In this case, he would perceive a "gravitational" component of force per unit volume to the right of magnitude $4\rho$.  The combined gravitational accelletion would be perpendicular to the liquid surface.
